# Confusion on defining data for trendline in a graph

Tags: r, plot

So I set up my graph to be:

```
ten <- c(0.2,0.16,0.17,0.188)
fifty <- c(0.1,0.24,0.17,0.166)
hundred <- c(0.3,0.16,0.16,0.14)
fiveh <- c(0,0.02,0.04,0.022)

plot(c(10,10,10,10,50,50,50,50,100,100,100,100,500,500,500,500),c(ten,fifty,hundred, fiveh), 
    ylab= "% of Impaired Rivers", xlab= "Number of Observations", main= "samples from all rivers")
```

and I'm trying to use abline function to create a trendline in my graph but got confused on how to define my values.

Help on how to make a proper trend line would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By basic R,(also, you can use `rep( ., each = )` to state `c(10,10,.....)`)

```
df <- c(ten,fifty,hundred, fiveh)
x <- rep(c(10,50,100,500), each = 4)

plot(x,df , 
     ylab= "% of Impaired Rivers", xlab= "Number of Observations", main= "samples from all rivers")
model <- lm(df ~ x)
abline(model, col = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: When I try to plug in this equation its saying that dummy is not found. How should I fix this?

Comment: @raynerperdana I'm really sorry. I usually use `dummy` as a data and forgot to change it's name in code above. I edit my code  as `model <- lm(df ~ x)`. Pleas try again, and it will not print error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try a `tidyverse` approach, here is how:

### Packages

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
```

### Create a data.frame

```
ten <- c(0.2,0.16,0.17,0.188)
fifty <- c(0.1,0.24,0.17,0.166)
hundred <- c(0.3,0.16,0.16,0.14)
fiveh <- c(0,0.02,0.04,0.022)

df <-
  tibble(
    x = c(10,10,10,10,50,50,50,50,100,100,100,100,500,500,500,500),
    y = c(ten,fifty,hundred, fiveh)
  )
```

### How to

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x,y))+
  geom_point()+
  labs(
    y = "% of Impaired Rivers",
    x = "Number of Observations",
    title = "samples from all rivers"
  )+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm",se = FALSE)
```

[image]